# Neo4j: Alternative Filter using list (General Approach)

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Im trying to filter based on a list that will be applicable to a general filter as long the list has the properties of the node, its trying to filter for.

```
UNWIND [{id:'1002',name:'Ford', type:'4-wheel'}] as row
MATCH (c:Car)
WHERE c[head(keys(row))]=row[head(keys(row))]
RETURN c
```

My problem is that the query filters as OR boolean and not AND boolean. (i.e. the reults return any combination of the property of node). However I just want the node that has all the properties listed.

Comment: Not clear what your use case is. Do you want `Car` nodes that have: (1) all the property *names* in a `row` (but the values can differ), or (2) all the property names and values in a `row`, or (3) something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this as an approach:

```
WITH keys({id:'1002',name:'Ford', type:'4-wheel'}) AS required
MATCH (c:Car)
WITH c, required, keys(c) AS toCheck, size(required) AS reqSize
WITH c, reqSize, required + toCheck as matched
UNWIND matched as matchedItems
WITH c, reqSize, matchedItems, COUNT(matchedItems) AS counted WHERE counted > 1
RETURN CASE WHEN size(collect(counted)) = reqSize THEN c ELSE null END
```

Basically, the operation is to create a list of keys that you are looking for and add it to a list of the keys in the node you are checking.

Next, group the key names by key name with a count, retaining only the duplicate key names, those with a count of two (the counts can only be one or two if the key names in the required list and the checked list are unique within the lists).

FInally, if the count of duplicate key names matches the length of the list of required keys, the node contains all the required keys.

You can reduce a lot of the 'WITH'ery in the above query. It's only there to show the logic behind the thinking.